Laravel retrieve images from storage public folder after deploying on shared hosting
Developers. I am working on an API project and there is image uploading in many pages, and I was storing the images like this
public function store(StorePlatformRequest $request)
{
    $request->validated($request->all());

    $filePath = $request->file('logo')->store('platforms_logos', 'public');

    $platform = Platform::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'logo' => Storage::url($filePath),
    ]);

    return new PlatformResource($platform);
}

and for example the logo image field in the database is storing a value like this
/storage/platforms_logos/wg3p4shWA3C9GGDEca4fDFSezVNn5eNWZsaD45HO.png
Now I uploaded my project on a shared hosting and the old images that was uploaded when I was working on local is retrieving successfully and working fine because I changed the localhost URL in the frontend pages to retrieve the links from the deployed app
But somehow when I am calling any function that includes image uploading it's not working, the image is uploaded successfully in the storage/app/public folders and the name of it is stored in the database, but I can't retrieve it anymore.
And when I tried to access the image directly from the browser it said 404 not found, but it's uploaded successfully in the folder
I thought it might be storage link problem and added this to web.php file and called it
Route::get('storage_link', function () {

    \Artisan::call('storage:link');

    dd("Storage is linked");

});

But nothing solved
Can any one help me with what I am missing?

Delete the folder public>storage first and then execute storage_link function

@ArjanShrestha it worked thanksss

Ok lets close this question by accepting the answer

Delete the folder public>storage first and then execute storage_link function
